# solr 8 nested documents / how to use Child Doc Transfomer

Tags: solr

from documentation draft i can see that SOLR 8 has some improvements on [nested documents](https://builds.apache.org/view/L/view/Lucene/job/Solr-reference-guide-8.0/javadoc/searching-nested-documents.html)

i've followed that guide and tried this:
create core

```
➜  ./bin/solr create -c test
```

post a nested json

```
➜  ./bin/post -c test nested.json
```

query all docs

```
➜  curl "localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=*:*"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "ID":[1],
        "title":["Cooking Recommendations"],
        "tags":["cooking",
          "meetup"],
        "posts.ID":[2,
          5],
        "posts.title":["Cookies",
          "Cakes"],
        "posts.comments.ID":[3,
          4],
        "posts.comments.content":["Lovely recipe",
          "A-"],
        "id":"2bbde94d-3058-49d2-a53b-74dbc2d417e0",
        "_version_":1633529758781276160},
      {
        "ID":[6],
        "title":["For Hire"],
        "tags":["professional",
          "jobs"],
        "posts.ID":[7,
          10],
        "posts.title":["Search Engineer",
          "Low level Engineer"],
        "posts.comments.ID":[8,
          9],
        "posts.comments.content":["I am interested",
          "How large is the team?"],
        "id":"8276a056-d731-4707-81ec-bbc3624e7763",
        "_version_":1633529758785470464}]
  }}
```

query with [Child Doc Transformer](https://builds.apache.org/view/L/view/Lucene/job/Solr-reference-guide-8.0/javadoc/searching-nested-documents.html#child-doc-transformer)

```
➜  curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?fl=ID,[child childFilter=/comments/content:recipe]&q=ID:1"

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"ID:1",
      "fl":"ID,[child childFilter=/comments/content:recipe]"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field content",
    "code":400}}
```

what i'm missing here?
do i need to enable something more to use this query `q=ID:1, fl=ID,[child childFilter=/comments/content:recipe]` ?

more: in that document the query response is a json document complete with child, instead if i do a simple query i still have a flattened document

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/test/get?id=2bbde94d-3058-49d2-a53b-74dbc2d417e0

{
  "doc":
  {
    "ID":[1],
    "title":["Cooking Recommendations"],
    "tags":["cooking",
      "meetup"],
    "posts.ID":[2,
      5],
    "posts.title":["Cookies",
      "Cakes"],
    "posts.comments.ID":[3,
      4],
    "posts.comments.content":["Lovely recipe",
      "A-"],
    "id":"2bbde94d-3058-49d2-a53b-74dbc2d417e0",
    "_version_":1633529758781276160}}
```